# processing columns in apache beam? mainly forward fill

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm trying to interpolate (forward-fill) values of a table.
input: a BigQuery table with n+1 columns where n are a bunch of readings and +1 is the Time column (The time when the reading was made). Most of these columns are empty. 
output: BigQuery table with the same n+1 columns, such that the empty values are replaced with the last known readings. (empty values at the beginning of time are ignored).

This is equivalent to pandas df.fillna(method='pad').

I would like to run This problem on huge tables using googles dataflow service through apache-beam.

It seems Beam Is great at handling rows but I can't seem to find a way to handle columns. Obviously once I've got a column I can easily iterate over it and interpolate the values as I go.

Although I'm not sure how memory works in dataflow. We need to make sure that it can handle the amount of data necessary.

```py
beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(table_path))
```

When reading a Table from Big Query one gets a Pcollection of rows
how do I get a column?
Even a query returns the same....

Answer (score 1):

If the forward fill your attempting is only at the end of each column, I would suggest using a combiner to find the last value in each column that was populated based upon the timestamp of the row.

```
ALL_MY_COLUMNS = ['foo', 'bar', ...]


class FindLastValue(core.CombineFn):
  def create_accumulator(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # first dict stores timestamps for columns while second dict stores last value seen
    return ({}, {})

  def add_input(self, mutable_accumulator, element, *args, **kwargs):
    for column in ALL_MY_COLUMNS:
      # if the column is populated and we haven't captured the value before or the timestamp of the element is greater then the value we have seen in the past then we will record this as the last known value. 
      if element[column] is not None and (mutable_accumulator[0][column] is None or mutable_accumulator[0][column] < element['timestamp']):
            mutable_accumulator[0][column] = element['timestamp']
            mutable_accumulator[1][column] = element[column]

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators, *args, **kwargs):
    # merge the accumulators based upon which has the smallest timestamp per column
    merged = ({}, {})
    for accum in accumulators:
      if element[column] is not None:
         if merged[0][column] is None or merged[0][column] > accum[0][column]:
            merged[0][column] = accum[0][column]
            merged[1][column] = accum[1][column]
    return merged

  def extract_output(self, accumulator, *args, **kwargs):
    # return a dict of column to last known value
    return accumulator[1]


def update_to_last_value(value, side_input):
  for column in ALL_MY_COLUMNS:
    if value[column] is None:
      if side_input[column] is None:
        # What do you want to do if the column is empty for all values?
      else:
        value[column] = side_input[column]


p = ... create pipeline ...
data = 'Read' >> p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(table_path))
side_input = 'Last Value' | CombineGlobally(sum).as_singleton_view()
# take the data that you computed as the 'last' value for each column and provide it to a function which updates any columns that are unset.
output = 'Output' >> data | Map(lambda main, s: update_to_last_value(main, side_input), side_input)
... any additional transforms that you want.
```

The above pipeline will parallelize well because you will compute the last value in parallel (this is the power of the combiner). Afterwards you'll be able to update all records in parallel since the last value has been computed.

Note that this won't solve arbitrary sparse sections in columns. Are these readings occurring at a regular frequency such that you can guarantee that every Y rows there is guaranteed to be a value?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid if you are using beam, you will have to write your own DoFn to handle it. Something like (pseudo code):

```
DoFn(input_element):
  for all the field_to_fill repeat:
    input_element.field_to_fill = NEW_VALUE;
  emit input_element
```

And apply this to the whole data set (i.e. the one from beam.io.read()).

My answer is limited to beam.  There might be feature in bigquery can do column access easily.

Comment: Thank you, for the quick reply. I guess this can work, but is there a way to do this parallelly on all the columns?  I have thousands of columns and because each of them is self-contained I could theoretically be able to run this code on all of them at the same time, where each run only updates a single column.

Comment: updated the pseudo-code. I guess in that case, if I understood the situation correctly, one may just repeatedly fill all the fields in one DoFn? This brings parallelisl, but of course still between rows.  Another workaround is, if you convert data into proto, maybe you can specify default value for all the fields you want to fill, which then in that case will populate automatically.

Comment: Hmm, It seems i wasn't clear about what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks again, You see the value I want to fill with is the last known value of the column. So for example, if for column k the value at time t is 5 and time t+1 it's empty I want to fill it with 5. So for each column, we have to process the rows serially to know which value to fill with, but because the columns are independent we can apply this transformation parallelly on all columns simultaneously. I assume the only way to do this is by applying a stateful transformation where I save the last known value. My question remains how do I apply this transformation parallel on all columns.

Comment: Is the forward fill always at the end of the column when ordered by timestamp or are there sparse gaps in the data?

Comment: The forward fill is sparse and the data is irregular you cannot know ahead of time how sparse it is. The forward fill isn't always at the end of the column, in fact, the opposite is true, the reason for the forward fill is to fill empty values with the closest possible past value. it may be that the second row of a column has a value and the third row is empty we wish to fill the third row with the value from the second, it could be that between the 3rd and the 600th rows all the values are full and then between 600-700 they are empty we wish to fill those 100 rows with the value from 600.